# trying to tar a directory lists the directory instead

Tags: linux, bash, compression, zip, tar

so I did this

```
tar cvzf test.zip FP
```

with the intention of creating a zip of the directory FP

however, it instead lists the directories inside the zip

```
FP/
FP/php/
FP/php/pdf/
FP/php/docs/
FP/aspnet/
FP/aspnet/pdf/
FP/aspnet/docs/
```

how do I go about tarring the directory?

Comment: Do you want a ZIP file or a gzipped tar file? You are currently creating the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command is good indeed.

Listing appear when specifying v option (in 'cvzf')

You can check what a gzipped tar file contain by running

```
$ tar tzvf test.zip
```

By the way you should avoid to put .zip extension on a "gzipped" tar file. If you really want to make a zip, use 'zip' package instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think it DID create it.  The list is just the command being verbose (-v).

Comment: you're right...the thing is that would create a .tar.gz file with a zip extension instead of a legitimate zip...do you know how to get it to create an actual zip?

Comment: z option in tar is gzip.  I think you need to do it in separate operations; make the tar and then zip it separately.